# Maven option suddenly disappeared in Eclipse import

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have maven projects imported in Eclipse before.  But today, I picked a wrong folder for Eclipse workspace, and then I closed Eclipse and opened it again with the correct folder, but then the Maven option disappeared when I tried to import an existing Maven project from a code repository.  If I right click on

```
  project-->Configure
```

I don't see the "convert to Maven project" option.

And also, for other Maven projects that I already imported before, their Libraries tab under "Java Build Path" used to have

```
 "Maven Dependencies"
```

but now it has:

```
 "Persisted container [org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER for project].
```

It seems that the Maven in Eclipse has messed up.  Anyone knows how to fix it?  Many Thanks.

Comment: recreate project

Comment: that's the existing project I cloned from a repository

Comment: reimport it again

Comment: I did, but the Maven option isn't there

Comment: Reimport as maven project.

Comment: from project --> import.... right?  but there is no option for Maven.  I used to have it. Other ways to import as maven project?

Comment: chekc if you have m2e plugin installed in current workspace

Comment: You can install it from eclipse market place. First search for maven in market place under help and if you find maven is installed then un install it and re install it again from market place.

Comment: The trouble is  for other Maven projects that I already imported before, I can't find Maven anywhere as well

Comment: @Prasad Reddy Thank you very much.  I updated the software/plugins and it seems working now.

Comment: @jlp ..No Problem.